# dynamic input value in my vf page is not getting save while I save vf page as an attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, pdf

I have a requirement that I have to create a form where some values will be prepopulated and some values will be filled by user then on clicking on button, page will be rendered as PDF and then attach in notes and attachment. I can see input values in my PDF page but same value does not populate in notes and attachment PDF.

Please find code as below:

VF page:- renderasPDF.vfp

```
<apex:page renderAs="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf == $CurrentPage.parameters.vcity, '', 'pdf')}" controller="DisplayPDFController">
   
    <apex:form id="Employerreg">
     <apex:outputText value="{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.CM__r.Name}/ JO#:{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.JobOrderNum__c}" label="CM"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="H2AReferral" title="H2A Referral Questionnaire Form">
        <apex:pageblockSection id="pbsId" columns="1" >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputText value="Employer Information" style="font-size:150%;"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputText label="Employer:" value="{!joDetails.Account__r.Name}"/>
            <apex:outputText label="Job Order:" value=" {!joDetails.Job_Order__r.DOLCaseNum__c}/SWA#:{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.StateCaseNum__c}"/>
            <apex:outputText label="Address:" value="{!joDetails.Account__r.ShippingStreet} {!joDetails.Account__r.ShippingCity} {!joDetails.Account__r.ShippingState} {!joDetails.Account__r.ShippingCountry} {!joDetails.Account__r.ShippingPostalCode}"/>
            <apex:outputText label="Phone:" value="{!joDetails.Account__r.Phone}"/>
             <apex:outputText label="Contract Period:" value="{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.Contract_Start_Date__c}-{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.Contract_End_Date__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            
            <apex:outputText value="Do you require help obtaining legal U.S. work authorization? (ex. H-2 Visa, sponsorship, etc.) ?"/>   
                   
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!workauthorizationYes}" label="Yes"/>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',workauthorizationYes==true)}" >
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',workauthorizationYes!=true)}" >
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!workauthorizationNo}" label="No"/>
                  
                 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',workauthorizationNo==true)}">
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',workauthorizationNo!=true)}" >
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            
                 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                 
                     <apex:outputText value="Job Description"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.ExpReq__c}"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.ComInst__c}"/>
                <apex:outputText value="{!joDetails.Job_Order__r.JobDesc__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputText value="Applicant Information" style="font-size:150%;"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                 <apex:outputText label="Date Contacted" value="{!joDetails.contact__r.FirstContactDate__c}"/>
            
        <apex:inputText rendered="{!OR($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='',$CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='false')}" id="vName" value="{!vName}" label="Vendor Company Name" /> 
       <apex:outputText rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true'}" value="{!vName}" label="Vendor Company Name"/> 
                 
         
     
        
            
            <apex:inputText value="{!tableContent1}"/>
    
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                        
            
            <apex:pageblockSection id="pbsId2">
                
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!checkYes}" label="Yes"/>
                  
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',checkYes==true)}" >
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',checkYes!=true)}" >
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!checkNo}" label="No"/>
                  
                 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',checkNo==true)}">
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!AND($CurrentPage.parameters.isPdf=='true',checkNo!=true)}" >
                    <img src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            
           </apex:pageblockSection>
            
             
        
                  
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            
            <!--:commandButton value="Generate PDF" action="/apex/renderAsPdf?isPdf=true"/-->
            <apex:commandButton value="Save Attachment" action="{!pdfAction}"/>
            
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        
        <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class DisplayPDFController {
    public String MstrId{get;set;}
    private final string PstrId{get;set;}
    public String PDFNo{get;set;}
    public String EFNo{get;set;}
    public boolean show{get;set;}
    public boolean showpdf{get;set;}
    public string vName {get; set;}
    public string vpereson {get; set;}
    public string vcity {get; set;}
    public string vcountry {get; set;}
    public string amount {get; set;}
    public boolean checkYes{get; set;}
    public boolean workauthorizationYes{get; set;}
    public boolean workauthorizationNo{get; set;}
    public boolean checkNo{get; set;}
    public string tableContent1{get; set;}
    private final Job_Order_Details__c joDetails;
    public Contact conDetails;
    public DisplayPDFController() {
        PstrId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        
        joDetails =  [select id,Account__r.Name,Account__r.ShippingStreet,Account__r.ShippingCity,Account__r.ShippingState,
                      Account__r.ShippingCountry,Account__r.ShippingPostalCode,Account__r.Phone,
                      Job_Order__r.CM__r.Name,Job_Order__r.JobOrderNum__c,Job_Order__r.DOLCaseNum__c,Job_Order__r.StateCaseNum__c,Job_Order__r.DOL_SDateRec__c,
                      Job_Order__r.DOL_EDateRec__c,Job_Order__r.ExpReq__c,Job_Order__r.JobDesc__c,Job_Order__r.ComInst__c,
                      Job_Order__r.Contract_Start_Date__c,Job_Order__r.Contract_End_Date__c,Job_Order__r.HourlyRate1__c,Job_Order__r.Add_A__c,
                      contact__c,
                      contact__r.FirstContactDate__c,contact__r.name,contact__r.MailingStreet,contact__r.MailingCity,contact__r.MailingState,contact__r.MailingCountry,contact__r.MailingPostalCode, 
                      contact__r.Phone,contact__r.OtherPhone from Job_Order_Details__c  where id='a0y8F0000002ewzQAA'];
        
        conDetails = [select id from contact where id=:joDetails.contact__c];
        MstrId = conDetails.id;
        system.debug('MstrId===>'+MstrId);
    }
    
    public Job_Order_Details__c getjoDetails() {
        return joDetails;
    }
    
    public PageReference pdfAction()
    {

        PageReference savepage ;
        savepage = Page.renderAsPdf;        
        savepage.getParameters().put('isPdf','true');
        savepage.getParameters().put('id',MstrId);
        system.debug('id:- '+MstrID);
        blob pdfBlob;
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            pdfBlob = savepage.getContentAsPDF(); //generate the pdf blob
        } else { 
            pdfBlob = Blob.valueOf('Test');
        }
        List<ContentDocumentLink> notesattch = [select id, ContentDocument.Title,LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId =: MstrID order by ContentDocument.Title asc];    
        system.debug('notesattch## ' + notesattch);
        if(notesattch.size() > 0)
        {
            string title =  notesattch[0].ContentDocument.Title;
            system.debug('title111 ' + title);
            List<String> titleSplit = title.split('R');
            //String FinalTitle = titleSplit[0]+'R0'+notesattch.size();
            String FinalTitle = 'R0'+notesattch.size();
            system.debug('FinalTitle22 ' + FinalTitle);
            PDFNo=FinalTitle;
            
            ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
            conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // to use S specify this document is in Salesforce, to use E for external files
            conVer.PathOnClient = FinalTitle+'.pdf'; 
            conVer.Title = FinalTitle; 
            conVer.VersionData = pdfBlob;
            
            
            system.debug('conVer@@ ' + conVer);
            insert conVer;  
            
            Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:conVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;
            
            ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = New ContentDocumentLink();
            conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = MstrID;
            conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDoc; 
            conDocLink.shareType = 'V';
            insert conDocLink;
            //update conDetails;
            
            //show=false;
            savepage.setRedirect(true);
            //showpdf=true;
            return savepage;
            /*
            PageReference savepage2 = Page.renderAsPdf;
            savepage2.getParameters().put('isPdf','true');
            savepage2.getParameters().put('id',MstrID);
            if(!show)
                savepage2.getParameters().put('show','0');
            savepage2.setRedirect(true);
            return savepage2;*/
            
        }
        
        
        {
            ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
            conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // to use S specify this document is in Salesforce, to use E for external files
            conVer.PathOnClient = PDFNo+'.pdf'; 
            conVer.Title = PDFNo; 
            conVer.VersionData = pdfBlob;
            insert conVer;  
            
            Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:conVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;
            
            ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = New ContentDocumentLink();
            conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = MstrID;
            conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDoc; 
            conDocLink.shareType = 'V';
            insert conDocLink;
            //Addtext = 'File Attached';
            
            update conDetails;
            
            show=false;
            showpdf=true;
            PageReference savepage2 = Page.renderAsPdf;//Cafactionpage;CAFFormPDF
            savepage2.getParameters().put('isPdf','true');
            savepage2.getParameters().put('id',MstrID);
            if(!show)
                savepage2.getParameters().put('show','0');
            savepage2.setRedirect(true);
            return savepage2;
        }
        
        //PageReference Pdf = new PageReference('/'+MstrID);
        //pdf.setredirect(True);
        //return Pdf;        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Blob.getContent` and `Blob.getContentAsPDF` run a separate context as a callout. That means any data you've saved in the running page won't be reflected in the PDF you generate. You need to either pass the data to the page generating the PDF somehow, or you must save, and then perform the PDF generation in a separate transaction. I typically do this with an oncomplete.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="createPDF" rerender="form" action="{!generateThePdf}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Save Attachment" action="{!saveData}" rerender="form" 
   oncomplete="createPDF()" />
```

Comment: My requirement is to not save user input data in database. However user input data should display in attach PDF. Please help with the same code. I have changes my code from Blob.getContentAsPDF to Blob.getContent but still it is working same as before.

Comment: @vidushiagarwal Yes, like I said, the separate page cannot see the data you collected in your page. You must arrange for it to receive the data somehow. For example, you might create some HTML and use Blob.toPDF, or you might pass the data through URL parameters.